# Homebrew's php-config returns wrong extension dir

Tags: php, c++, macos, makefile, homebrew

I'm creating a `Makefile` to compile my own PHP extension and install it into local PHP installed from homebrew.

So... here's the deal:

```
➜  weeaboo  which php
/usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php
➜  weeaboo  which php-config
/usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php-config
➜  weeaboo  /usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php-config --extension-dir
/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
➜  weeaboo  cd $(/usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php-config --extension-dir)
cd: no such file or directory: /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
```

Why is it missing? And why is PHP uses another directory? How do I get the correct extension directory in Makefile or with `php-config`?